# Having trouble with pointers and references in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am attempting to call a function that will change the reference to the variables but I keep getting a bad access everytime that I run the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "calculations.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char input[12];
    string input2;
    string nameOfFood;
    int *numberOfServings = 0;// THIS IS WHERE I KEEP GETTING THE BAD    ACCESS
    int *calories = 0;
    float *fatInGrams = 0;
    float *carbsInGrams = 0;
    float *fiberInGrams = 0;
    float *proteinInGrams = 0;
    int count = 0;
//    Open an output file
    ofstream outData; //IGNORE
//    Start a loop

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        //    On the console, ask if the user ate. If the answer is No, be creative, but polite in your answer.
        cout << "did you eat? yes or no" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if (input[0] == 'y'){
            cout << "Please enter the name; number of servings; calories; amount of fat";
            cout << "; number of carbs; amount of fiber; and the amount of protein" << endl;
            cin >> nameOfFood
            >> *numberOfServings
            >> *calories
            >> *fatInGrams
            >> *carbsInGrams
            >> *fiberInGrams
            >> *proteinInGrams;
            calculate(nameOfFood, numberOfServings, calories, fatInGrams,carbsInGrams, fiberInGrams, proteinInGrams);
            i = 0;
            count++;

        }
        if (input[0] == 'n'){
            i = 5;
        }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    cout << "calories is " << &calories << endl;
    cout << "number of servings is " << &numberOfServings << endl;
```

the calculate function has a header file of :

```
#ifndef calculations_hpp
#define calculations_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void calculate(string nameOfFood, int *numberOfServings, int   *calories, float *fatInGrams, float *carbsInGrams, float *fiberInGrams,   float *proteinInGrams);

#endif /* calculations_hpp */
```

and the calculate function file is

```
#include "calculations.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void calculate(string nameOfFood, int *numberOfServings, int    *calories, float *fatInGrams, float *carbsInGrams, float *fiberInGrams, float *proteinInGrams){
    *numberOfServings = 24;
    *calories = 15;
}
```

I can't seem to figure this out, I know it can be done as I have seen it before in an Objective-C college class any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just stop using pointers. Remove all pointers from the code. There, that's it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to pass the address of a valid variable to calculate.

```
string nameOfFood;
int   numberOfServings = 0;
int   calories = 0;
float fatInGrams = 0;
float carbsInGrams = 0;
float fiberInGrams = 0;
float proteinInGrams = 0;

calculate(nameOfFood, &numberOfServings, &calories, &fatInGrams, &carbsInGrams, &fiberInGrams, &proteinInGrams);
                      ^Address of numberOfServings
```

In the calcualte function.

```
calculate(string nameOfFood, int* numberOfServings, int* calories, float* fatInGrams, float* carbsInGrams, float* fiberInGrams, float* proteinInGrams)
 {
     // Inside the function.
     // numberOfServings is a pointer to the variable.

     // Thus *numberOfServings dereference the pointer and
     // allows you to assign the variable that it points at.

     *numberOfServings = 24; // modifies the variable that was pointed at.
```

Comment: Ok, then when I'm in the calculate function how does that work?

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize a variable like:

```
int *numberOfServings = 0;
```

it points to nothing. Dereferencing such a pointer leads to undefined behavior. Hence, the line:

```
    cin ....
        >> *numberOfServings
```

is wrong.

The simplest fix is to declare the variable `numberOfServings` as an object of type `int`, not a pointer.

```
int numberOfServings = 0;
```

and then change where it is read into as:

```
    cin ....
        >> numberOfServings // Drop the *
```

Make similar fixes to

```
int *calories = 0;
float *fatInGrams = 0;
float *carbsInGrams = 0;
float *fiberInGrams = 0;
float *proteinInGrams = 0;
```